# Choosing between overloading primitive types or using a Number object reference

Tags: java, overloading

I have a confusion about the following options for a numeric method

1. Overloading

> ```
> int abs(int)
> long abs(long)
> double abs(double)
> ```

2. Parent class reference

> Number abs(Number)

which approach is best and what is the difference between these two approach ?

If we use the parent class reference then overloading is not needed. Is there any problem of using the second style.

When we should go for First approach and when for second ?

Comment: Just for the record:I guess there won't be much other answers coming so please consider accepting the most helpful answer!

Answer (score 2):

The major difference: your option 1 works on **primitive** types.

Whereas option 2 works for **reference** types (aka objects).

Of course, because of auto-boxing and unboxing, you might be able to have just one implementation of that `abs(Number)` method. But: keep in mind that *boxing* doesn't come for free!

In other words: option 1 allows you more fine granular control - you know that your method is really called with an int, long, float, double. The downside is that you probably start duplicating code.

Option 2 probably works without duplicating code - but it has a certain price tag at runtime, as each and any time you invoke that method with a primitive type value ... a new Number object will be created (just to be thrown away afterwards).

Comment: When we should go for First approach and when for second in a real situation ?

Comment: I gave you the pros and cons. I am not here to do your job and make the decisions. In other words: you have to consider what is the best choice given your context /requirements. Nobody else can tell you that.

Comment: Unless you have a demonstrable bottleneck (i.e. a demonstrable performance problem hitting this particular area of the code) then the better approach would most likely be the simpler approach. On the other hand, if you have a demonstrated bottleneck in which this logic is involved, and want to try to optimize it, then consider the more complicated approach. And, if you want to be really rigorous, benchmark the before & after to ascertain exactly what the more complicated approach buys you in performance. Just my 2 cents.

Answer (score 1):

Option #2 is not as trivial as you made it look for at least two reasons:

- The `Number` abstraction will force you to actually use a particular type of number in your implementation, as it only provides `intValue()`, `longValue()`, `doubleValue()`, etc.
- To make this usable, you will probably want to use generics, which makes it even more cumbersome to implement (so that client code can make use of concrete number types with no downcasting).

  ```
  <N extends Number> N abs(N number) {
      // choose an actual primitive type to use, e.g.: number.doubleValue()
      // TODO: create a new instance of N if number.doubleValue() is negative
  }
  ```

So you will probably end up checking every known type of number inside that method anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I would borrow the python Zen and say
Explicit is better than implicit

So the first option of overloading is better.
That gives you more granular control without using conditions

Also it avoids creating objects by the compiler so I would assume it is faster